# Sed problem  in a Bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, sed

I'm having a problem using the `sed` command .  I'm trying to write a bash script that does the following :

1. search for the line that contain `:@`
2. then save the line that contained `:@` and replace it with new line

as in the following:

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "Please enter the ip address of you file"
read ipnumber
find=`grep ':@' application.properties` # find the line
input="connection.url=jdbc\racle\:thin\:@$ipnumber\:1521\:billz" # preparing new line
echo `sed "s/'${find}'/'${input}'/g" application.properties` # replace old with new line
```

The problem is: nothing happens.

I've already tried to use `"${find}"`  instead of `'${find}'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several problems with that snippet. I recommend you learn bash's syntax a little better before writing scripts in it.

Anyway, if you want to edit a file, you want a file editor. sed is not a file editor. I believe this will do what you want.

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter the ip address: " ipnumber

ed -s application.properties << EOF
/:@/c
connection.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@$ipnumber:1521:billz
.
w
EOF
```

What that ed script says is: `/:@/c` - on the first line containing `:@`, **c**hange the line with everything following until a line containing only a `.`. Then `w` to **w**rite the changes to the file.

See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/doku.php?id=howto:edit-ed for help with editing using ed, and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide to learn bash.

Update:
sed can be used to achieve the same, but it can't edit files, it can only be used to create a new file.

```
# POSIX
sed "/:@/c\
connection.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@$ipnumber:1521:billz" application.properties
```

Here sed will output the file with the changes applied. You can redirect to a new file, then move that file over the old one. GNU sed also has a non-standard `-i` option that does the last part transparently. GNU sed also doesn't require you to have that newline in the sed script.

```
# GNU sed
sed -i "/:@/c connection.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@$ipnumber:1521:billz" application.properties
```

Note that the ed will only replace the *first* line that matches the regex while sed will replace *all* lines matching that regex.

Comment: you are genius.....Thanks man Thanks , is there way to use sed ??

Comment: @moata_u yes, I've updated the answer to also explain how to do it with sed.

Answer (score -1):

my problem was  : i was using an variable name (value) ,, which is reserved :)) 
Solution is :

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Please Enter The ip address : " ipnum 
find=`grep ":@" application.properties`
test="connection.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@$ipnum:1521:e"
sed -i "s/"$find"/"$test"/g" application.properties
```

---

THANKS  geirha

---

Comment: You were not using any reserved variable names in your initial code, you simply had the shell and sed syntax wrong. Again I recommend reading the bash guide I linked to in my answer. You are still using quotes wrongly, and it may fail to work if the find variable contains whitespace, glob syntax, regex syntax or slashes.